# Programming a rock paper scissors html game

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a rock paper scissors game for my computer science class. The game is a human versus the computer. I have gotten the code to the point where the webpage looks correct, but when the user clicks on one of the icons to select either rock paper or scissors,nothing happens. Can someone help me with connecting the picture buttons to the function that runs the game? Also, if I could get help with how to add code that keeps score of the game, and counts how many wins the human and computer each get? Thanks. The code is below.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Rock Paper Scissors Shoot!</title>
<style>
body {
    font-family: Roboto, Arial; 
}

.choose img {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 20px;   
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="choose" align="center">
    <h1 id="question">Let's play rock paper scissors! Choose a move</h2>
    <img alt="Dwayne THE ROCK Johnson"src="http://d39ya49a1fwv14.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/The-Rock-4.png" id="rock">
    <img alt="Lined paper"src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/writing-on-paper-clipart-black-and-white-1206556249326967385nexxuz_Loose_Leaf_Paper.svg" id="paper">
    <img alt="Scissors"src="http://www.wpclipart.com/education/supplies/scissors/round-tip_scissors_blue.png" id="scissors">
</div>

<script>

    var computerChoice = math.random();
    var userChoice = null;

    if (computerChoice < .33) {
        computerChoice == "rock";
    } else if (computerChoice < .66) {
        computerChoice == "paper";
    } else {
        computerChoice == "scissors";   
    };

   function convertUserChoice() {
        $('#rock').click(function() {
            userChoice == "rock";
        });
        $('#paper').click(function() {
            userChoice == "paper";
        });
        $('#scissors').click(function() {
            userChoice == "scissors";
        });
    };

    if (userChoice == computerChoice) {
        alert ("Tie!");
    } else if (userChoice == "rock") {
        if (computerChoice == "scissors") {
            alert ("You win!");
        } else {
            alert ("You lose.");
        };
    } else if (userChoice == "paper") {
        if (computerChoice == "rock") {
            alert ("You win!");
        } else {
            alert ("You lose.");
        };
    } else if (userChoice == "scissors") {
        if (computerChoice == "paper") {
            alert ("You win!");
        } else {
            alert ("You lose");
        };
    };

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using jQuery, but didn't included it.

Add this to your `<head>`:

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`

Another solution without jQuery would be using the `onClick` function.

```
<img alt="Dwayne THE ROCK Johnson"src="http://d39ya49a1fwv14.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/The-Rock-4.png" id="rock" onClick="onRockClick()">
```

Comment: adding <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> to the head didn't seem to work. what would the actual block of code for the onClick function look like?

Comment: While a valid suggestion, IMO there's absolutely zero reason to use the inline event attributes anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be something like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Rock Paper Scissors Shoot!</title>
<style>
body {
    font-family: Roboto, Arial; 
}

.choose img {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 20px;   
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="choose" align="center">
    <h1 id="question">Let's play rock paper scissors! Choose a move</h2>
    <img alt="Dwayne THE ROCK Johnson"src="http://d39ya49a1fwv14.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/The-Rock-4.png" id="rock">
    <img alt="Lined paper"src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/writing-on-paper-clipart-black-and-white-1206556249326967385nexxuz_Loose_Leaf_Paper.svg" id="paper">
    <img alt="Scissors"src="http://www.wpclipart.com/education/supplies/scissors/round-tip_scissors_blue.png" id="scissors">
</div>

<script>

    var computerChoice = Math.random();
    var userChoice = null;

    if (computerChoice < .33) {
        computerChoice = "rock";
    } else if (computerChoice < .66) {
        computerChoice = "paper";
    } else {
        computerChoice = "scissors";   
    };

   function convertUserChoice(userChoice) {
   if (userChoice == computerChoice) {
        alert ("Tie!");
    } else if (userChoice == "rock") {
        if (computerChoice == "scissors") {
            alert ("You win!");
        } else {
            alert ("You lose.");
        }
    } else if (userChoice == "paper") {
        if (computerChoice == "rock") {
            alert ("You win!");
        } else {
            alert("You lose.");
        }
    } else if (userChoice == "scissors") {
        if (computerChoice == "paper") {
            alert ("You win!");
        } else {
            alert("You lose");
        }
    }
     
    }

    $('#rock').click(function() {
            convertUserChoice("rock");
        });
        $('#paper').click(function() {
            convertUserChoice("paper");
        });
        $('#scissors').click(function() {
            convertUserChoice("scissors");
        });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Calling `computerChoice = Math.random();` at the end of your convertUserChoice function, makes the AI work.

Comment: it works in the run code snippet option on this site but not on the html link on my computer. How exactly should I work in                     computerChoice = Math.random(); to make it work

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Rock Paper Scissors Shoot!</title>
<style>
body {
    font-family: Roboto, Arial; 
}

.choose img {
width: 150px;
margin: 20px;   
}
#result {color:red}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="choose" align="center">
<h1 id="question">Let's play rock paper scissors! Choose a move</h1>
<h2 id="result"></h2>
<h2>[Player One] <span id="playerScore">0</span> - <span id="computerScore">0</span> [Computer]</h2>
<img alt="Dwayne THE ROCK Johnson" src="http://d39ya49a1fwv14.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/The-Rock-4.png" id="rock">
<img alt="Lined paper" src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/writing-on-paper-clipart-black-and-white-1206556249326967385nexxuz_Loose_Leaf_Paper.svg" id="paper">
<img alt="Scissors" src="http://www.wpclipart.com/education/supplies/scissors/roundtip_scissors_blue.png" id="scissors">
</div>

<script>
$(function(){

var computerScore=0,
  playerScore=0;

function setText(txt){
$("#playerScore").text(playerScore);
$("#computerScore").text(computerScore);
$("#result").text(txt);
}

function makeComputerChoice(){
  var computerChoice = "";
  var r = Math.random();
  if (r < .33) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
  } else if (r < .66) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
  } else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";   
  };
  return computerChoice;
 }


function makeUserChoice(userChoice){
  var computerChoice = makeComputerChoice();
  var outcome = "";
if (userChoice == computerChoice) {
    outcome="Tie!";
} else if (userChoice == "rock") {
    if (computerChoice == "scissors") {
        outcome="You win!"; playerScore=playerScore+1;
    } else {
        outcome="You lose."; computerScore=computerScore+1;
    };
} else if (userChoice == "paper") {
    if (computerChoice == "rock") {
        outcome="You win!"; playerScore=playerScore+1;
    } else {
        outcome="You lose."; computerScore=computerScore+1;
    };
} else if (userChoice == "scissors") {
    if (computerChoice == "paper") {
        outcome="You win!"; playerScore=playerScore+1;
    } else {
        outcome="You lose"; computerScore=computerScore+1;
    };
};
  setText(userChoice+" vs "+computerChoice+" = "+outcome);
};

 //add event listeners:
 $('#rock').click(function() {
        makeUserChoice("rock");
    });
    $('#paper').click(function() {
        makeUserChoice("paper");
    });
    $('#scissors').click(function() {
        makeUserChoice("scissors");
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I took almost all of the code from @Moob and it works quite well I am not sure why you all down voted him. I am giving him an up vote for this. I needed to put in the opening and closing tags but that is about it.

Answer (score -2):

There's a fair bit wrong with what you have so far. I've made a few improvements to get it working, make a new computer choice each turn and to keep score.

```js
$(function(){
 
  var computerScore=0,
      playerScore=0;
  
  function setText(txt){
    $("#playerScore").text(playerScore);
    $("#computerScore").text(computerScore);
    $("#result").text(txt);
  }
  
  function makeComputerChoice(){
      var computerChoice = "";
      var r = Math.random();
      if (r < .33) {
        computerChoice = "rock";
      } else if (r < .66) {
        computerChoice = "paper";
      } else {
        computerChoice = "scissors";   
      };
      return computerChoice;
  }


    function makeUserChoice(userChoice){
      var computerChoice = makeComputerChoice();
      var outcome = "";
    if (userChoice == computerChoice) {
        outcome="Tie!";
    } else if (userChoice == "rock") {
        if (computerChoice == "scissors") {
            outcome="You win!"; playerScore=playerScore+1;
        } else {
            outcome="You lose."; computerScore=computerScore+1;
        };
    } else if (userChoice == "paper") {
        if (computerChoice == "rock") {
            outcome="You win!"; playerScore=playerScore+1;
        } else {
            outcome="You lose."; computerScore=computerScore+1;
        };
    } else if (userChoice == "scissors") {
        if (computerChoice == "paper") {
            outcome="You win!"; playerScore=playerScore+1;
        } else {
            outcome="You lose"; computerScore=computerScore+1;
        };
    };
      setText(userChoice+" vs "+computerChoice+" = "+outcome);
    };
  
  //add event listeners:
  $('#rock').click(function() {
            makeUserChoice("rock");
        });
        $('#paper').click(function() {
            makeUserChoice("paper");
        });
        $('#scissors').click(function() {
            makeUserChoice("scissors");
        });
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Roboto, Arial; 
}

.choose img {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 20px;   
}
#result {color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="choose" align="center">
    <h1 id="question">Let's play rock paper scissors! Choose a move</h1>
  <h2 id="result"></h2>
<h2>[Player One] <span id="playerScore">0</span> - <span id="computerScore">0</span> [Computer]</h2>
    <img alt="Dwayne THE ROCK Johnson" src="http://d39ya49a1fwv14.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/The-Rock-4.png" id="rock">
    <img alt="Lined paper" src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/writing-on-paper-clipart-black-and-white-1206556249326967385nexxuz_Loose_Leaf_Paper.svg" id="paper">
    <img alt="Scissors" src="http://www.wpclipart.com/education/supplies/scissors/round-tip_scissors_blue.png" id="scissors">
</div>
```